# How to embed flutter web in HTML as a iframe (fullscreen)?

Tags: html, flutter, iframe, embed

I want to display a specific link of my flutter web app in an iframe.

**Purpose:**
Create multiple dynamic websites on custom domains managed with 1 flutter web app

**Things I have tried:**

1. Making iframe dynamic using javascript code, but onLoad does not trigger
2. iframe with 100% height and width does not work

**Problem:**
100% width works fine using:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
but the height does not take up the entire space

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to do it.

```
        iframe {
            width: 100% !important;
            min-width: 100%;
            height: 100vh !important;
            align-self: center;
            border: 0;
        }
```

The important thing to note was that scroll was not working when flutter web was put in iFrame in Safari.

Solution:

```
 <script>
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});
 </script>
```